# Lua inheritance

Tags: oop, class, inheritance, lua, multiple-inheritance

I have two classes in Lua.

```
test1 = {test1Data = 123, id= {0,3}}
function test1:hello()
    print 'HELLO!'
end
function test1:new (inp)
    inp = inp or {}
    setmetatable(inp, self)
    self.__index = self
    return inp
end

test2 = {}
function test2:bye ()
    print 'BYE!'
end
function test2:create_inst( baseClass )
    local new_class = {}
    local class_mt = { __index = new_class }
    function new_class:create()
        local newinst = {}
        setmetatable( newinst, class_mt )
        return newinst
    end
    if baseClass then
        setmetatable( new_class, { __index = baseClass } )
    end

    return new_class
end

a = test1:new({passData='abc'})
print (a.test1Data, a.passData, a:hello())
c = test2:create_inst(a)
print (c.test1Data, c.passData,c:hello(), c:bye())
```

I want to inherit `test2` from `test` but leave in the specified `test2` methods `bye`.
Everything works except for `bye:method`.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return an empty table in `test2:create_inst()`, at no point does anything reference `test2`, so the function `test2:bye()` is not in the table returned by `test2:create_inst()`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `test2` actually has nothing to do with the table you are instancing, this `new_class` table you return from `test2:create_inst` is the new instance. So naturally it has no field named `bye`. Simple modification:

```
function test2:create_inst( baseClass )
    ...
    if baseClass then
        setmetatable( new_class, { __index = baseClass } )
    end
    ...

    function new_class:bye()
        print("bye!")
    end
    return new_class
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer want to implement Multi-Inheritance that new_class inherit "test2" and "baseClass".

```
local function search(k, objlist)
    local i = 0
    local v
    while objlist[i] then
        v = objlist[i][k] 
        if v then return v end
    end
end

function class(...)
    local parents = (...)
    local object = {}
    function object:new(o)
        o = o or {}
        setmetatable(o, object)
        return o
    end
    object.__index = object
    setmetatable(object, 
        {__index=function(t, k)
        search(k, parents)    
    end})
    return object
end

c = class(a, test2)
print(c.test1Data, c.passData,c:hello(), c:bye())
```