# Why can I not access lua functions in a table with the "name"

Tags: arrays, lua

I am new to Lua, but not to programming. I have extensively used Java in the past. I decided the best way to learn Lua would be to do some reading around. I decided to implement a very basic version of object orientation and did the following:

```
Object = {
    class = "object";
}

function Object:getClass()
        return self.class;
    end

function Object:printClass()
        print(self:getClass());
    end

print(Object:getClass()); --Returns "object"
print(Object["getClass"); --Returns the memory address of the function getClass()
print(Object["getClass"]()); --Should print the results of the function. Instead throws error "input:6: attempt to index a nill value (local self)" which, if I am understanding correctly, is the equivalent of a NullPointerException in Java.
```

Why does Lua throw the error above? What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to access functions with their string "name"? The question is **NOT** about how to use Lua in an object-oriented way, which has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927364/lua-class-inheritance-problem).

I tested the code [here](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in Lua, `Object:getClass()` is syntactic sugar for `Object.getClass(Object)` (if you want to get technical, it only evaluates the expression `Object` once). So when you call `Object["getClass"]()`, you are calling the function with no parameters. That will cause a problem when the function tries to access its first parameter: `self`, which will be `nil`.

Hence the error, "attempt to index a nil value (local self)".

That's also where the magic variable `self` comes from. When you declare a function with `:`, the syntactic sugar adds a parameter to the front of the parameter list that it calls `self`.

Comment: So `Object["getClass"](Object)` will work but will evaluate `Object` twice (which usually isn't a problem but could be).